# Требуется имя метода

Tags: c#, строки, mvvm, методы, void

Ошибка в propertyName - Требуется имя метода. Не понимаю в чем проблема, можете помочь? Как я думаю ошибка в части

> NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)

, но не уверен, как именно исправить.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TimeTrack.ViewModel
{
    public class DataManageVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventHandler(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PropertyChangedEventHandler Принимает в аргументах не строку а объект PropertyChangedEventArgs

Это семантика PropertyChangedEventHandler:

```
public delegate void PropertyChangedEventHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e);
```

Поэтому, чтобы исправить ошибку нужно:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```